# apply css to previous all images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to apply some CSS to all previous image tags.

```
$('#'+globe).prevAll().removeClass('t2').addClass('t1');
```

This is applying CSS to all previous elements including `div`.

How can it be restricted to only `img` elements?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here, perhaps try providing a link or a working example?

Comment: @ johnkavanagh question updated..

Comment: $('img').prevAll().removeClass('t2').addClass('t1');

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question is clear for me. Select all the previous sibling elements except the _div_ elements.

Comment: @undefined: I think its *Select all the previous siblings of type img*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
$('#'+globe).prevAll().removeClass('t2').addClass('t1');
```

to

```
$('#'+globe).prevAll('img').removeClass('t2').addClass('t1');
```

**OR**

```
$('img',$('#'+globe).prevAll()).removeClass('t2').addClass('t1');
```

Comment: The last one won't work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use only css.

```
img{
  style here for all images
}
img:last-child{
   different style for last image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#'+globe).prevAll('img').removeClass('t2').addClass('t1');
```